# Is there a way to invoke unix shell scripts or Java jars with using Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, unix

I am thinking if it's possible to call Unix shell scripts or a Java jars from within a procedure in Oracle. My requirement is as commit happens to a table, I should generate a script and telnet it to a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes is possible, check the following documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm

Or you can invoke directly telnet through TCP with the package UTL_TCP:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_tcp.htm

Or you can invoke a WebService that make the work using the package UTL_DBWS:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_dbws.htm